# Trigger after insert SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter

Tenho uma tabela de **atividades** (referente a Deposito ou Saque de um app de cofrinho) se insere ID (PK automatica), valor (double) Dia (Text) tipo (pode ser 0 - para depositos / 1 - saques) 
e eutra tabela chama **total** com um capo valor(double).. \

Quero criar um trigger que depois de inserir na tabela atividades, atualiza o campo valor da tabela total,
que "recalcula" o total do cofrinho (a **soma  dos valores** de atividades com **tipo = "0"** **menos** a soma  dos valores de atividades com **tipo = "1"** ) (depósitos - saques)..

Como ficaria esse trigger?

```
db.execute('CREATE TRIGGER update_total AFTER INSERT ON atividades '
            ' BEGIN '
              'UPDATE total as t SET t.valor, VALUE = '
              '(SELECT SUM(valor) FROM atividades WHERE tipo = "0")'
             ' - (SELECT sum(valor) FROM atividades WHERE tipo = "1") '
            'END');
```

Minha tentativa foi mal sucedida.

Comment: Tente: `(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = "0" THEN valor WHEN tipo = "1" THEN -valor ELSE 0 END) FROM atividades)`.